# How to know if the caret position is in between {} characters in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a textbox that may contain any string. Let's say the current value in textbox is

`Testing {0} behaviour`.

I want to know if the current caret position (either during clicking of text box or entering values) is between the two curly  braces ('{' and '}') and if yes, I want to know the content inside that curly braces set.

Note: There might be multiple curly braces set in the string as well. eg -

`Testing {0} behaviour of {1} iterations`

I want the function to return true and the respective integer (0 or 1) if the cursor is inside any of the curly braces set.

I can get the current cursor position using:-
`elem.selectionStart` where `elem` is the textbox.
Regex is not my strong suit, which is why I am facing difficulty here. I believe it is possible to do it with a long string manipulation logic but I am trying to find an elegant solution.

Comment: so did you find any code that figures out where the cursor is in the middle of the string?

Comment: `elem.selectionStart` gives the current cursor position, where `elem` is the textbox

Comment: What do you expect when the string is `Testing {case {0} behavior of {1} count} iterations`?

Comment: To demonstrate why that example makes regex an invalid solution, a naive regular expression would match `{case {0}` and `{1}` in that string. A sufficiently more complex one would be able to get `{0}` and `{1}`, but ultimately you would always be able to construct an example that any given regex would eventually fail against, and the regex would also be quite unreadable at that level of complexity.

Comment: We only need to match curly braces that have only integers inside them.

Comment: So if you had something like `{testing}`, it shouldn't match that?

Comment: The caret position can be either at the selection start or selection end depending on which direction the selection is made. Example  abc`d{efg`}hij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We only need to match curly braces that have only integers inside them.

You can match them using `/\{(\d+)\}/g`. `(...)` in a regular expression is referred to as a *capturing group*, and you can use it to isolate important information such as the placeholder's index in this case.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('textarea');

elem.addEventListener('keyup', feedback);
elem.addEventListener('click', feedback);

function feedback () {
  const index = getIndex(this);
  
  if (index === -1) console.log('no placeholder selected');
  else console.log(`placeholder at index ${index} selected`);
}

function getIndex (element) {
  const placeholder = /\{(\d+)\}/g;
  const { value, selectionStart, selectionEnd } = element;

  for (let match; (match = placeholder.exec(value)) !== null;) {
    if (match.index < selectionStart && placeholder.lastIndex > selectionEnd) {
      return Number(match[1]);
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Testing {0} behaviour of {1} iterations</textarea>
```

Comment: hi! same thing I need to do it for angular brackets <> 
how to do?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the working example with React, but here are the key parts:

1. Find your matches with: [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) where `/\{\d+\}/g` is the Regex. This expression matches 1-N amount of digits that are enclosed in `{`, and `}`.
2. Go through all your matches with [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and use [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) your match.
3. Check that your `selectionStart` is between the `indexOf` your match, and the length of the match. If it is, you've hit your mark!

**Put together**:

```
let cursorPosition = e.target.selectionStart
let text = e.target.value
let matches = text.match(/\{\d*\}/g)

let result = matches.find(match => {
  const matchIndex = text.indexOf(match)
  return cursorPosition > matchIndex && cursorPosition < matchIndex + match.length
})

if (result) {
  console.log(result.substring(1, result.length-1))
}
```

Feel free to play around with the input below and see if it meets your criteria.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: "Testing {0} {behavior} of {1} iterations {123}"
    }
  }
  
  handleClick = (e) => {
    const cursorPosition = e.target.selectionStart
    const text = e.target.value
    const matches = text.match(/\{\d+\}/g)
    
    const result = matches.find(match => {
      const matchIndex = text.indexOf(match)
      return cursorPosition > matchIndex && cursorPosition < matchIndex + match.length
    })
    
    if (result) {
      console.log(result.substring(1, result.length-1))
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onClick={this.handleClick} defaultValue={this.state.text} style={{width: "400px"}}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((<App/>), document.getElementById('testing'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="testing"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We look up all the braces in the text, we index the start and end, compare the current position with all found in the text and return the result. The performance might be somewhat bad for very long strings, but as long as it is not, I do recommend using the most readable solution to you.

```js
const string = 'Testing {0} behaviour of {1} iterations';

function lookAtPosition(text, position) {
  return Array.from(string.matchAll(/\{(\d+)\}/g)).map(result => { 
    return { 
      number: result[1],
      start: result.index,
      end: result.index + result[0].length,
    };
  }).find(({ start, end }) => start <= position && end >= position);
}

console.log(lookAtPosition(string, 3));
console.log(lookAtPosition(string, 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can just go straight to the caret position with a regex.
A single regex check if you know the caret position is all you need.
Construct the regex with the caret position:

```
var rx = new RegExp("^[\\S\\s]{1," + strCaretPos + "}({[^{}]+})");
```

Run the regex on the string

```
if ( rx.exec( input ) )
{
      // Test the match position of group 1 
      if ( posGrp1 < intCaretPos && (posGrp1 + length(Grp1)) > intCaretPos )
      {
         // winner, winner, chicken dinner
      }
}
```

Example checking ***CaretPos*** = 50, on target string

`asdfasdfasdfasdptptpttfyytukertuketuyyyy{yyyyyyyy<caret>yyyyyuuuuuuuuuuuu}yyyy55555555u{gggggggggppppppp}puuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuugg}gS`

We check group 1 like this

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 : len 74 ) 
asdfasdfasdfasdptptpttfyytukertuketuyyyy{yyyyyyyy<caret>yyyyyuuuuuuuuuuuu}  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 40 : len 34 ) 
{yyyyyyyy<caret>yyyyyuuuuuuuuuuuu}
```

and see that it satisfies ***Grp1 < CaretPos && (Grp1 + length(Grp1)) > CaretPos***

Here is how the regex works

```
 ^ 
 [\S\s]{1,49} 
 (                             # (1 start)
      {                           # Open brace
      [^{}]+                      # Not braces
      }                           # Close brace
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: It basically matches the closest `{..}` to the caret position. A simple math check is then all you need. Operation could be done thousands of times per second. This is a very good way to do it !!